# How to hide a div of class ui-grid-solo JQM

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How can I hide this div my code is below:

```
 <div class="ui-grid-solo">
    <div class="ui-block-a" id="commentsection">
     <label for="comments">Comments:</label>
         <input type="text" name="comments" id="comments" value="">
         <a href="javascript:;" data-role="button" data-iconpos="right" id="comment">Comment</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(".ui-grid-solo").hide();` ??

Comment: Just try it: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=hide+div+jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery there is a function .hide(), so what you would do is this:

```
$(document).ready(function{
    $(".ui-grid-solo").hide();
});
```

Comment: never use `.ready` in jQM.